# MS Graph Api missing permissions

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I deployed the app to Teams.
If I'm not logged in as admin, I get this error:

```
HTTPMessageHandler.ts:31          GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans/prpAA7SlvE6gwSEEjcESs5gACiII/tasks 403 (Forbidden)
```

```
GraphErrorHandler.ts:62 Uncaught (in promise) Error: You do not have the required permissions to access this item.
at Function.value (GraphErrorHandler.ts:62:18)
at GraphErrorHandler.ts:89:31
at l (regeneratorRuntime.js:72:17)
at Generator.\_invoke (regeneratorRuntime.js:55:24)
at Generator.next (regeneratorRuntime.js:97:21)
at tslib.es6.js:74:71
at new Promise (\<anonymous\>)
at gs (tslib.es6.js:70:12)
at Function.value (GraphErrorHandler.ts:86:106)
at e.\<anonymous\> (GraphRequest.ts:386:37)
```

In https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/ I have admin approved these rights:
[image]

In azure portal I have approved these rights:
[image]

In APP code I set:

```
"requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "Microsoft Graph",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "Tasks.ReadWrite",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "Tasks.Read.Shared",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "User.Read",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "User.ReadBasic.All",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "Calendars.Read",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "Files.Read.All",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "Sites.Read.All",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "Group.Read.All",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "Group.ReadWrite.All",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "Tasks.Read",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "People.Read",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

And finally

```
"signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg"
```

I really don't know what I'm going wrong and why the users in the organization still don't have the necessary rights What I am I missing please?

Answer (score 2):

For listing [tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannerplan-list-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for a plan you don't need all those permissions.  What you have is way overkill.

Yon only need ONE of these permissions.

- Tasks.Read
- Tasks.ReadWrite
- Group.Read.All
- Group.ReadWrite.All

So to read a plan tasks only you really only need delegated Tasks.Read only, nothing else.

If you are using Application authentication then you can't use this API, it requires a authenicated user beaer token to be able to use this API.

I normally see Forbidden from this API when using a user that doesn't have permission to see that plan.

A [plan belongs to a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/plannergroup-list-plans?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), so the user accessing the plan must be a member of that group to be able to see the plan and the plan tasks.

You should be able to experiment with this API using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) either against the sample tenant or login and use it against your own tenant.

Comment: Yes, I know it's overkill, I have so many rights just to solve this problem. I need the application to have permission to read all tasks of all users, so I gave not delegated, but application rights to Tasks.Read.All and Tasks.ReadWrite.All, expecting that to be enough, but no. Shouldn't these application rights be enough? So I need beaer token, I will try it. Thank you

Comment: @Tomas As mentioned in the answer, Planner api doesn't support application permissions. If your application runs as a background service or daemon without a signed-in user, then Planner api doesn't support this scenario. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/announcing-updates-to-the-planner-api-in-microsoft-graph/

Comment: Users are logged in but not members of all groups, so they can only read plans they are members of. I need a user in my organization to be able to read everyone else's plans without being a member of them. If I understand correctly, this is not possible yet.

Comment: If you really need to read all tasks, and since you can get Group.ReadWrite.All, one way to do this is to enumerate all the groups with plans and add your user to that group(s).  That way you will always have access to all plans.  The problem is that user will show up in the group list.